# Alternative to jQuery's .last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use the 1.3.2 library which unfortunately does not support the last functionality. This causes my function to fail:

```
$op.last().next().after($op);
```

> "$op.last is not a function"

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/uscyH/

I have been unsuccessful at rewriting this functionality in pure js, any suggestions? Note, I will also need the .first(), but I'm assuming I will be able to extrapolate that from the .last alternate code. Many thanks-

Comment: then use a more recent jQuery

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the `:last` selector, which existed since 1.0:

```
$op.filter(':last')
```

Answer (score 5):

To get the last element, do this:

```
$op.slice( -1 )
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uscyH/4/

> The jQuery `.slice()` method is patterned after the JavaScript .slice()
>   method for arrays. One of the features that it mimics is the ability
>   for negative numbers to be passed as either the `start` or `end`
>   parameter. If a negative number is provided, this indicates a position
>   starting from the end of the set, rather than the beginning.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/slice/

---

To get the first element do this:

```
$op.eq( 0 )
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uscyH/5/

Comment: How would you go about accessing the first element?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$op` is the collection of options, get the first DOM element in the collection using:

```
var first = $op[0];
```

and the last using:

```
var last = $op[$op.length-1];
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could find the last or first item with this method
http://jsfiddle.net/uscyH/3/

```
alert("Last is: "+$("option:last").html()+" and first is: "+$("option:first").html());​
```

**Update**: Looks like you have lots of ideas to choose from now. Feel free to use whatever approach you would like. This approach is probably not the fastest one since it is doing two DOM queries instead of operating on the list you already appear to have stored in an array. It's nice to see how jQuery has been so powerful even back in these versions. Thanks for the ideas everyone!

Comment: The OP already has the elements inside the `$op` collection, and he would like to retrieve the first/last elements of that collection. You're doing DOM queries which is something different.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas; thanks for your thoughts. You're right that he wasn't asking for a DOM query. I thought, though, that he might not need to create a variable to hold the collection depending on what he is trying to do. He may decide to stick with his `$op` or abandon it if he prefers a DOM query.

Comment: DOM queries are expensive. I always try to minimize their usage. Using a `$op` collection is preferred.

Comment: Well-said; but they are easier to read / understand than `slice(-1)` :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$($op[$op.length-1]).next().after($op);
```

You can also choose to extend jquery and create your own last method.